# Need to get the Total hours calculated from the multiple entries of hour field in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**serializers**

```
class Consolidated_serializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    project_name = serializers.CharField(source='project.project_name')
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    user_id = serializers.CharField(source='user.id')

    class Meta:
        model = Timelog
        fields = ('id','username','user_id','project_name','date','hours',)
```

**viewset**

```
class Total_hours_viewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = models.Timelog.objects.all().annotate(sum_delta=Sum('hours'))
    serializer_class=serializers.Consolidated_serializers
```

The result I am getting is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 13,
        "username": "vinoth",
        "user_id": "14",
        "project_name": "Inhouse Timesheet",
        "date": "2022-03-24",
        "hours": "08:00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "username": "vinoth",
        "user_id": "14",
        "project_name": "Inhouse Timesheet",
        "date": "2022-03-24",
        "hours": "08:00:00"
    }
]
```

But the result I need is:

```
[
    Total hours: 16:00:00
    {
        "id": 13,
        "username": "vinoth",
        "user_id": "14",
        "project_name": "Inhouse Timesheet",
        "date": "2022-03-24",
        "hours": "08:00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "username": "vinoth",
        "user_id": "14",
        "project_name": "Inhouse Timesheet",
        "date": "2022-03-24",
        "hours": "08:00:00"
    }
]
```

I tried using the above code, but I couldn't able to get the total hours in the JSON view for multiple entries. Can you please help me to get the total hours by adding the multiple entries of hour field in the model?

Comment: Timelog.objects.aggregate(Sum('hours'))

Comment: i tried that but it is showing an error as "return queryset.model._meta.object_name.lower()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'model'"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
class Consolidated_list_serializers(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        hours = instance.aggregate(hours=models.Sum(models.F('hours')))
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        ret.append((hours.get('hours').seconds)/3600)# convert to hours 
        return ret 

class Consolidated_serializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    project_name = serializers.CharField(source='project.project_name')
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    user_id = serializers.CharField(source='user.id')

    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = Consolidated_list_serializers
        model = Timelog
        fields = ('id','username','user_id','project_name','date','hours',)


class Total_hours_viewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = models.Timelog.objects.all()
    serializer_class=serializers.Consolidated_serializers
```

Comment: It is working but the total hours is showing in seconds is there any ways to change it from seconds to hours ?

Comment: i updated my code to get hours as output. please check and let me know if you have any issues